# Usar array en VC2008

Tags: c++

Tengo el problema de no poder usar arrays en visual studio 2008 en c++.Tengo instalado visual studio 2008 profesional con SP1. He estado buscando por internet y al parecer es posible incluir arrays, pero no consigo hacerlo. Alguno de vosotros lo ha conseguido?

He encontrado varios links que afirman que se puede hacer, varias de ellas son de Microsoft, pero no consigo avanzar.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c87b07b-f91d-4915-aa7e-68c10eddf4b8/c-include-array?forum=vclanguage

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb982198(v=vs.90).aspx

Qualquier idea, sugerencia, ayuda... se agradece. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::array` se incorporó al estándar en el estándar C++11 (que data del 2011). La versión 2008 vio la luz tres años antes, por lo que no incorpora el citado estándar ni, por supuesto, `std::array`.

La única solución en tu caso es instalar un VS más moderno (el 2010 ya incorpora ciertas características de C++11).

Comment: Pero por lo que pone en los links que he puesto arriba no se deduce que es posible? O me estoy equivocando?

Comment: @Andermutu Extracto de la primera repuesta del primer enlace "_Make sure you have VS2008 with SP1 AND the Feature Pack installed.  If you don't you won't have array._". Ignoro si el "_Feature Pack_" incorpora algunos añadidos de C++11 aunque intuyo que ya no se encontrará disponible en la MSDN

Comment: Si el feature pack se encuentra disponible y ya lo tengo instalado. Aun asi sigo sin poder incluir los array.

Comment: @Andermutu no tengo ese IDE para poder hacer pruebas... lo más seguro entonces es que el proyecto no esté incluyendo el directorio donde se encuentra el TR1. Esto tendrás que hacerlo a mano

Comment: Gracias eferion por tu ayuda. Para incluir a mano como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: @Andermutu En el menú contextual del proyecto elige "_properties_". Busca la sección "_Configuration Properties_" -> "_VC++ properties_". Tendrás que añadir la ruta a las cabeceras de TR1 en "_Include directories_" y, posiblemente, las ruta a los precompilados en "_Library directories_"

Comment: Te cuento, he conseguido incluir la libreria array en aplicacion de consola y funciona aparentemente bien. Al escribir `#include <array>´no me da ningun error y puedo usar std::array. Pero al intentar hacer una aplicacion de consola de smart device de win 32 y al incluir la libreria me da este error: `Error 1 fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'array': No such file or directory c:\Users\P\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prueba1\Prueba1\Prueba1.cpp 5 Prueba1´

Comment: Porque en aplicacion para pc puede funcionar bien y para smart device no?

Comment: @Andermutu El conjunto de librerías que se usa para compilar para smart device es distinto que para pc de escritorio... un pc de escritorio tiene un SO y el device otro diferente (aunque ambos se llamen Windows). Estás intentando una compilación cruzada y es algo relativamente avanzado. Quizás es tan sencillo como repetir los pasos para este nuevo tipo de compilación...

Comment: Y como podria hacer para repetir la configuracion? Yo creo que lo hago del mismo modo.

Comment: @Andermutu el nuevo proyecto tendrá igualmente unas propiedades... incluye las dependencias a TR1 tanto de cabeceras como de librerías precompiladas

Comment: @Andermutu y si eso no funciona es que la característica no va a estar disponible para ese objetivo